# send mail with existing file as attachments using oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
attachments  shr_pkg_send_mail.array_attachments:=shr_pkg_send_mail.array_attachments();
b_input_file BFILE:= BFILENAME('mount_dir', 'test02.txt');
c_output_file CLOB;

BEGIN
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_output_file);
dbms_lob.open(b_input_file, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
 --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1');

dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => c_output_file, cache => false);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2');
dbms_lob.open(c_output_file, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('3');
dbms_lob.loadfromfile(c_output_file, b_input_file, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('4');
dbms_lob.close(b_input_file);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('5');
attachments.extend(1);
attachments(1).attach_name := 'test02.txt';
attachments(1).data_type := 'text/plain';
attachments(1).attach_content := c_output_file;                     SHR_PKG_SEND_MAIL.SEND_MAIL('EthicsandComplianceITSupport_ORG@dl.mgd.novartis.com','mansi.kekre@novartis.com','test','test',attachments => attachments);

dbms_lob.close(c_output_file);
END ;
```

ERROR

ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1014

ORA-06512: at line 8

Comment: Did you create directory 'mount_dir' in oracle ? Check this view (`select * from ALL_DIRECTORIES;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the directory path

```
select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name='MOUNT_DIR'
```

Check if this path exists on **database server** and oracle has read access to it.

Check if the file 'test02.txt' exits in this path and is accessible.

Give grants to this directory

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY MOUNT_DIR TO <some_user>;
```

And [here](https://davidalejomarcos.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/how-to-list-files-on-a-directory-from-oracle-database/) is something interesting, how to see files in directory with select, but you should have access to the SYS user.